# problems related to permutation and combination prove required

Tags: permutations, combinations

how to prove this one?
$n!=n^n-\binom{n}{1}(n-1)^n+\binom{n}{2}(n-2)^n-\cdots$
if you can please provide the interpretation of the formula. 
i have proved using induction.

my failed attempt
trying to convert RHS into LHS

Comment: Try to interpret the RHS as an inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$ S_n = \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q (n-q)^n.$$

Introduce
$$(n-q)^n = 
\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp((n-q)z)}{z^{n+1}} \; dz$$

which yields for the sum
$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(nz)}{z^{n+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q \exp(-qz) \; dz
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(nz)}{z^{n+1}}
(1-\exp(-z))^n \; dz
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(\exp(z)-1)^n \; dz.$$

This is
$$n! [z^n] (\exp(z)-1)^n
= n!$$

where we have used the fact that
$$\exp(z)-1 = z +\frac{1}{2} z^2 + \frac{1}{6} z^3 + \cdots$$